# Codename one Theme Layering Works

Tags: codenameone

How to use theme Layering in CodeName One ?

```
theme = UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Theme 1");           
UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(theme.getTheme(theme.getThemeResourceNames()[1]));
```

I have instantiated the primary and secondary theme .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first theme (0 in the array) is "Theme 1" which isn't guaranteed then changing your code from `setThemeProps` to `addThemeProps` will work.